# Created a function and need help counting blanks in a string

Tags: mysql

Here is my function which does not seem to work. Does anyone have suggestions??

```
 delimiter  # 
     Drop function if exists a_testbed.InternalBlankCount #  
         Create function a_testbed.InternalBlankCount ( 
         in_string int)  
        Returns int
          Begin 
        Declare v_blanks int; 
        if v_blanks is null then       
        Set v_blanks := 0;    
        else 
        Set v_blanks := length(in_string) - length(replace(in_string, ' ', ''));
        end if;     
        Return v_blanks; 
        end; # 

    Trying to produce output as a sample:
      select a_testbed.InternalBlankCount(hi how are you) #
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your input parameter as an integer is a problem... I would go with a varchar depending on the expected length you will legitimately be working on... Then, default the value of blanks to 0, then compute if the incoming string is NOT NULL

```
CREATE FUNCTION a_testbed.InternalBlankCount( in_string varchar(200)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
   Declare v_blanks int;
   Set v_blanks := 0;
   if NOT in_string is null then
      Set v_blanks := length(in_string) - length(replace(in_string, ' ', ''));
   END if;

   Return v_blanks; 
END
```